# Display command which would be run

Tags: powershell

How can I display (preview) the commands that would be run?

Existing code:

```
$sname = "svr01"
$dname = "prod"    

# Reload all views
foreach ($filename in Get-ChildItem -Path Views -Filter "*.sql")
{
Invoke-Sqlcmd –ServerInstance $sname -Database $dname -InputFile $filename.FullName
}
```

Intended Output:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd –ServerInstance svr01 -Database prod -InputFile C:\db\Views\AllParts.sql
Invoke-Sqlcmd –ServerInstance svr01 -Database prod -InputFile C:\db\Views\ActiveParts.sql
Invoke-Sqlcmd –ServerInstance svr01 -Database prod -InputFile C:\db\Views\OpenOrders.sql
Invoke-Sqlcmd –ServerInstance svr01 -Database prod -InputFile C:\db\Views\PastOrders.sql
```

I am used to bash scripting in Linux, where you can just put `echo` before the line to output it. Both `echo` and `Write-Host` in front of `Invoke-Sqlcmd` resulted in errors.

Comment: @briantist's `-WhatIf` approach is the way to go, but I'm curious what errors you saw, because prepending `Write-Host` should work fine in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `echo` (which is really `Write-Output`) or `Write-Host` or `Write-Verbose` work by quoting the following command. If you want to avoid escaping, use a here-string:

```
Write-Host @'
Invoke-Sqlcmd –ServerInstance $sname -Database $dname -InputFile $filename.FullName
'@
```

But even better is that commands in PowerShell which make changes *should* (but don't always) support a common parameter called `-WhatIf`.

Ideally, you would just add that to your call.

If the command does support it, you can also set your preference somewhere in the script before the command:

```
$WhatIfPreference = $true
```

It will then be inherited. You will have to find out for yourself if the command you're running supports it, which you can do with `Get-Help`.

#### Edit

After checking, it doesn't look like `Invoke-SqlCmd` (nor newer alternatives such as the ones available in dbatools) support `-WhatIf`.

I would actually say that you should add the support in your own script.

I know this might seem like a little much since you're just starting out but it does have advantages.

First things first, scripts work like commands in PowerShell which means they can also define parameters.

We can start at the top of your script and use the attribute `[CmdletBinding()]` to tell PowerShell you want to be able to use advanced function features, like `SupportsShouldProces` (this automatically enables the `-WhatIf` parameter on your script and you won't need to declare it manually).

Then we'll use the automatic variable `$PSCmdlet` and its method `.ShouldProcess()`.

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
param()

$sname = "svr01"
$dname = "prod"    

# Reload all views
foreach ($filename in Get-ChildItem -Path Views -Filter "*.sql")
{
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("DB $dbname on server $sname", "Executing SQL from file $($filename.FullName)")) {
        Invoke-Sqlcmd –ServerInstance $sname -Database $dname -InputFile $filename.FullName
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
 .\myScript.ps1 -WhatIf
```

Bonus: when you want it run it for real, using `.ShouldProcess()` gives you automatic `-Verbose` output if you ask for it:

```
.\myScript.ps1 -Verbose
```

What's nice about these, besides using actual PowerShell conventions is that it happens *on invocation* so you don't need to edit the script to do a dry run.

Comment: The `Write-Host` with the here-string did not expand the variable names.  It did however output the correct number of lines (matching the number of `*.sql` files in the Views folder).

Comment: @Steven you can use double quotes, but it won't properly expand some expressions like your last parameter. See my edit for a better alternative.

Comment: Double quotes did the trick! That's a good tip on adding WhatIf to the whole script.

Comment: This worked like a charm ... using `whatif`  ... thank you so much!